Why won't my washing machine drain pipe empty?
Our washing machine drains into a wall-mounted drain. The problem is that as soon as as the spin cycle is over the drain backs up and won’t go down. We have tried snaking it, taking the P-trap off and replacing it and snaking from there. Water will go down if it’s from just a regular pressure hose or cup. But as soon as the washer drains it stops working.
How do I go about fixing this? There not a clog obviously because water goes through. Is it just because the washer drain pressure is too high/ fast? We’ve been using a hose extender and draining out of the back door but I’m so over having to do that.

Does the house drain configuration include a standpipe? Can you attach a photo of the drain arrangement, or is it inside the wall? If inside the wall, how high is the drain hole on the wall? Pics please...

If you're sure there's no obstruction, the diameter of the pipe is clearly too small for the flow rate the washer is putting out.  Since you haven't given us any photos, it's hard to provide a solution.  You may be able to add a detention tank, where the washer drains to the tank, and the tank drains to the wall.  The tank would need to be large enough to hold the volume of water the washer uses for the largest cycle.

Does this answer your question? How can I stop my washing machine drain from overflowing?

Or this? Washing machine drain pipe backing up

I had the exact same problem with a rental unit.
The solution was, I hired a plumbing company to clean out the main house drain. They said there was a partial obstruction. Once cleaned out, there was no issues.

A washing machine dumps a lot of water fast.  the pipes must be completely clean to take it.  And large enough.  Not sure of the size needed, but might check if the inner diameter is smaller than 1.5 inch.
